# DNA fingerprinting

Tags: genetics, dna, forensics

About a month ago i performed a DNA fingerprinting lab and now i have a small lab report due in about two weeks.[image: Result of the DNA fingerprinting]
Questions:
What are some possible errors that can happen during the process of DNA fingerprinting?(non-human errors)

My research:
One of the errors that can happen during the process of making DNA fingerprint is when the microcentrifuge tubes are open air particles can get inside it. The air itself has many things especially bacteria that can possible get into the microcentrifuge and can cause false results.(Can someone confirm this)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**This should be a comment**

> The most common causes of failures related to the laboratory process
> were contamination and human error. Most human errors could be
> corrected, whereas gross contamination in crime samples often resulted
> in irreversible consequences. ([article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24905336))
>
> In DNA fingerprinting work, it is well known that, although fragment
> lengths of a sample are uncorrelated, measurement errors of fragment
> lengths are correlated. Unless the fragment length is very large, the
> measurement errors are directly proportional to fragment lengths. In
> the currently practiced matching procedures for forensic
> identification, these facts are ignored or inadequately used. Some of
> these issues are addressed in this study. ([article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8582356))

You should provide more information about the method(s) you used. Further you found:

> One of the errors that can happen during the process of making DNA
> fingerprint is when the microcentrifuge tubes are open air particles
> can get inside it.

This is error is not a *specific* DNA fingerprinting error, based on this I would suggest to read something about "DNA extraction/purification errors" like:

- foreign DNA in your sample
- Wrong phenol-chloroform ratio (I don't know if you used this --> reason why you should tell something about your methods)
- PCR errors
- etc..